# Error:Unable to install composer-cli

Tags: hyperledger-composer

When I run `npm install -g composer-cli` I get this error:

> "Need to have composer-cli installed at v0.15 or greater".

How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 5):

Try running the command with `--unsafe-perms` , like this:

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g composer-cli
```

Reference: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/454

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu (the supported Linux development environment) we do not recommend using sudo to install Composer.

The usual reason people would resort to sudo is a permission problem, but it is better to resolve the permission problem rather than use sudo.  Often the problem is the npm prefix which can get set to /usr/local to which the user doesn't have write access.  Issuing an `npm config set prefix /home/<myuser>/` will solve the problem.

You may have an old version of Composer or one of the components installed.  Try using `npm ls -g --depth=0` to see if you have some composer code already installed, and if so remove it with `npm uninstall -g composer-<component>` where  might be cli, or playground etc.  The retry the install-g command.

Comment: On Mac, it should be changed to npm config set prefix /Users/<myuser>/ If you have mistakenly run npm config set prefix /Users/<myuser>/, you can fix it by opening ~/.npmrc and change it back to /Users/<myuser>/ instead of /home/<myuser>/

Answer (score 0):

Try this....this is the command to install 0.20 version.

npm install -g composer-cli@0.20

Answer (score 0):

I changed my node version from

> 11

to

> 8.8.15

and did `npm install -g composer-cli`.It worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a 8.* node version, 
My solution was:

```
nvm install 8.9.0
nvm use 8.9.0
npm install -g composer-cli
```